# Appending new data whilst removing data seen by user from array swift 3

Tags: arrays, sorting, swift3

I'm trying to build a news reader app and currently have an Article object that returns an array:

```
class Article: NSObject, Mappable {
var author: String?
var title: String?
var desc: String?
var url: String?
var urlToImage: String?
var publishedDate: String?
var sent = false

required init?(map: Map){

}
```

I have added a boolean called Sent to keep track of whether the user has seen the article before, however each time I fetch news data it will override the existing Article Array.

I have tried using a method for removing duplicates in an array, however this does not keep track of whether the user has seen the article already or not.

What is the best approach to solving this problem? I know I have to iterate through the array each time the api is called but is there a better approach than this?

```
let newArticles = [Article]()
for (index, newArticle) in newArticles.enumerated() {

   if articles[index].title != newArticle.title {
       articles.append(newArticle)
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first recommend that all boolean variables start with a conditional word "is", "has", or "was". Secondly it sounds like your array would be perfect as an `OrderedSet` rather than and `Array`. An `OrderedSet` is an order collection of values that does not allow multiple entries of the same object. So I would have a `Set` (`NSSet`) of Article objects that have not yet been seen. Once the user has seen that Article mark it's `isSent` property as `true`. All other Articles in the `Set` that has not yet been seen yet will have it's `isSent` property to `false`.

And maybe change the wordage of your boolean to be "`isSeen`" instead of "`isSent`".

---

**EDIT**

```
let set = NSOrderedSet(objects: articles)
if let setArray = set.array as? [Any] {
    let filteredSet = setArray.filter({ (article) -> Bool in
        return article.isSeen == true
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. If the isSeen boolean is set to true and the user fetches more data from the API, wouldn't there be a duplicate since the isSeen bool would be initialised as false?

Comment: An object will have a memory address you will see printed out into your console when you do print(myObject). A `Set` will look at this memory address and only include new objects if the `Set` doesn't already contain an object with that memory address then it will be added. Duplicates in the sense means no 'identical' objects. It does not check against the values of the properties that are contain in that object. That would include your `isSeen` boolean. To descriminate against the values in the objects in the set you can filter the Articles by property values. See my edited answer.